# In MochaJS: How to run asynchronous tests sequentially?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

I'm using the [MochaJS](https://mochajs.org/) framework for unit testing NodeJS code.

The tests look like this:

```
import 'mocha';
import { assert } from 'chai';
import { describe } from 'mocha';

describe('Test Suite', () => {
    function execute(testData: string) {
        it('Individual Test', async function() {
            // await some asynchronous call using testData
            // do some asserts
        });
    }

    const testData: string[] = ["test 1", "test 2", "test 3"];

    for (const data: string of testData) {
        execute(data);
    }
});
```

It turns out that multiple tests (named 'Individual Test') will run in parallel. Is there any way to await each test so that it completes before the next one starts? I do not want to declare individual tests for each of the `testData` items, since that would be a lot of copy/paste.

Comment: If you write your tests without the wrapper function, do they work?

Comment: How do you know that it runs in parallel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you do not use --parallel flag of the mocha.

You have two options. Either use awaits in the async function in Individual Test.

Or you can use delete "async" and use done() for async tests. Call done() when tests should end. If you call it with an error, the test will fail. Make sure to call done() only once.

```js
it('Individual Test', function(done) {
    aPromise().then(v => {
      done();
    }).catch(done);
});
```

References:
done: https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code